# decorrelating detector

Tags: digital-communications

In this paper [decorrelating detector](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwib_8mEnvfmAhXK8OAKHSjjBuUQgAMoAHoECAEQAg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fscholar.google.fr%2Fscholar_url%3Furl%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Fprofile%2FH_Vincent_Poor%2Fpublication%2F3079471_Blind_Multiuser_Detection_A_Subspace_Approach%2Flinks%2F54a29de40cf256bf8bb0ce39%2FBlind-Multiuser-Detection-A-Subspace-Approach.pdf%26hl%3Dfr%26sa%3DX%26scisig%3DAAGBfm1WsNW1nVt0B5BklZgHmmR8VhjaRA%26nossl%3D1%26oi%3Dscholarr&usg=AOvVaw0HRxDgkAgXG0izxicwqV22) we have the decorrelating detector. With $K$ users, the correlation matrix of the signature waveform is $R=S^TS$ with $S=[s_1,...,s_K]$. Moreover $size(R)=K \times K$

This is my question: In the article (p $679$), we have: $d_1=\sum_{i=1}^K [R^{-1}]_{1,i}s_i$. But, how can we make this product, the elements do not have the same dimensions? In fact, $size(R^{-1})=K \times K$ and $size(s_i)=N \times 1$ with $N \neq K$

Answer (score 1):

It all works out because $[\mathbf{R}^{-1}]_{1, i}$ is just a number. It is the number in row $1$ column $i$ of the matrix $\mathbf{R}^{-1}$. So the product $[\mathbf{R}^{-1}]_{1, i}\mathbf{s}_i$ returns a vector of length $N \times 1$. See the line after Equation 10.